# How to set Spark timeout ( application Killing itself )

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark2.4.4

I want to add a security measure to my spark job, if they don't finish after X hours kill them selves. (using spark 2.4.3 in cluster mode in yarn mode)

Didn't find any configuration in spark that helps me with what I wanted .

I tried to do it this way:

```
    val task = new java.util.TimerTask {
        def run():Unit = {
            val p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("/bin/sh", "-c", s"yarn application -kill ${sc.applicationId}")) // this code can only run on the cluster
            p.waitFor()
            sc.stop()
        }
    }
    timeoutProcess.schedule(task, X) // where X is 10000 for 10s for testing
```

But doesn't seem to accomplish killing the application, would appreciate any idea or thought regarding this.

Tried to look around but didnt find any good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to set a timeout for a job is via yarn.

Check this hadoop [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-3813)

You can either use cli like :

```
yarn application -appId <your app id> -updateLifetime 3600
```

This will kill your application after 3600 `seconds` from the time you run this command.

Or you can use Rest end point to update this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you know maybe of any way of accomplishing this from within the Spark job it self?

Comment: either run the CLI way  mentioned in the answer like the way you are doing now..in the main driver program  or do a rest call .

Comment: Will test if running it via driver works. Thanks